# Spring Batch - interrupt thread when job stops

Tags: spring, spring-batch

On stopping a job the manual says

> The shutdown is not immediate, since there is no way to force immediate shutdown, especially if the execution is currently in developer code that the framework has no control over, such as a business service.

My long-running steps performs checks for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and throws `InterruptedException`. Surely there is some way to interrupt the thread running the job?

(Note: I'm using `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` with `TaskletStep`)

Comment: Can you add the batch xml and the tasklet in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bean to implement

```
ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> onApplicationEvent()
```

Then you can shut down the task.

```
@Component
 class ContextClosedHandler implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
@Autowired SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor;

  void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
     executor.shutdown();
  }       
}
```

This post about the lifecycle of beans might help as well

http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/spring-framework-an-introduction-part-ii-object-lifecycle-autowiring-internationalizationi18n/